# Magento home page

Tags: magento

I am working with a Magento install that I did not set up and am pretty green when it comes to its operation... There is a default page serving as the "home page" when there is already a page defined in the back-end as the "home page". The path in the URL reads as: `DOMAIN/index.php` but when I try to find said index file using google developer mode, I can find no such file that would generate the layout. I suppose I just don't have enough overall knowledge to figure out what is at work here. Can someone help me figure out why it's using the default home page instead of mine?

Answer (score 0):

On most webshops I've worked on the CMS home page wasn't really used. Instead of the CMS home it can be easier to use a custom template to setup the homepage with static blocks and what not.

If this is also the case for you, there might be two places you can find this custom template:

- In the layout xml files, search for`cms_index_index`?
- In backend, navigate to the CMS home page and go to the Design tab

About the index.php part: this is because you probably because you haven't enabled mod_rewrite in your server configuration

Comment: I figured that this is the case just didn't know how to articulate it as well. I know I have seen that xml file somewhere but haven't been able to nail it down in the layout folders.